# How to debug an Angular app that require remote assets with login

Tags: angular, debugging, visual-studio-code, configuration

I have an angular app that downloads resources from Cloudflare in order to get it up and running. The problem is that you have to login.
So when I run the debug mode in VSCode, the Chrome window that opens goes blank with the error:

```
arg1:
HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 200, statusText: 'OK', url: 'https://xxxx.cloudflareaccess.com/cdn-cgi/acce…xxxxxXvzw', ok: false, …}
defaultErrorLogger @ c:\Users\xxxxxxx\workspace\xxxx\xxxx\node_modules\@angular\core\fesm2015\core.mjs:6461
```

To resolve that and continue debugging, I need to open another window in the Chrome that was opened for debugging, login, return to the app window, and refresh.
I have to do that every day.
Isn't there a way to add the accesses in the launch.json so that it does it automatically?
It's quite annoying.

My actual launch.json is :

```json
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Chrome",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "chrome",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be authenticated and logged in to run remote resources. You could create SSH tunnel:

> Cloudflare can be used to create a zero trust configuration for the SSH connection between your local machine and the VM in Azure. To get started, create a free Cloudflare account, set up a domain, and enable the Access and Argo Tunnel products in your account.

https://developers.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-one/tutorials/ssh

https://bradyjoslin.com/blog/remote-vs-code/#vs-code-remote-ssh-extension